# How to hide scroll bar in scrollview xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am implementing my custom tab control, but i am struck with problem where i have used scrollview in horizontal mode to create scrolled tabs, here currently i am getting scrollbar but i just want to hide this and make a tab control same as android.
Is there any direct solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think theirs any direct solution available for that. You just have to create a custom renderer by extending the default scroll view renderer. Here's what I have done, I hope it may serve your purpose.

**Android Specific Code:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView), typeof(ResponsiveFramework.Droid.ScrollViewEXRenderer))]
namespace ResponsiveFramework.Droid
{
    public class ScrollViewEXRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.OldElement !=null)
            {
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropetyChanged;
            }

            e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropetyChanged;
        }

        private void OnElementPropetyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ChildCount > 0)
            {
                GetChildAt(0).HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS Specific Code:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView), typeof(ResponsiveFramework.iOS.ScrollViewEXRenderer))]
namespace ResponsiveFramework.iOS
{
    public class ScrollViewEXRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var result = this.Element.GetValue(ScrollViewPoperty.HorizontalScrollBarVisibleProperty);
            bool IsHorizontalScrollBarVisible = Convert.ToBoolean(result);
            if (IsHorizontalScrollBarVisible == false)
            {
                if (e.OldElement != null || this.Element == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                if (e.OldElement != null)
                {
                    e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;
                }

                e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        private void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.ShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is specific to Android.  The question was for Xamarin forms (including ios and other targets in the tags). -- Can you add more detail to the answer about using this for other targets as well? -- And at least a link as to how to hook this up (i.e. is the attribute enough, or do we have to do something in our XAML so that this gets used by the control we want to remove the scroll bars from?)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I have added code for IOS renderer. To hook hook up nothing to do in Xaml just export the renderer for the control which you want to use.As show in the sample above.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 https://github.com/veloxcore/Xamstrap you will find saample over here in src folder.